# Unable to set up hadoop on my local machine

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop as a pseudo stand alone application on my macbook, and I have been seeing errors.

When I try to execute `sbin/start-dfs.sh`, I get the following error.

```
$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Connection closed by ::1 port 22
Starting datanodes
localhost: Connection closed by ::1 port 22
Starting secondary namenodes [Kartiks-MacBook-Pro.local]
Kartiks-MacBook-Pro.local: Connection closed by 100.110.189.236 port 22
2018-01-22 00:20:19,441 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I used the following pages as my reference

1) http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

2) https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation

3) http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

None of the URLs to view either the namenode load for me

1) http://localhost:9870/ (from the Hadoop's website)

2) http://localhost:50070/ (from http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html)

I am using my personal login id from my Macbook.